# Is str_replace faster with array?

Tags: php, performance, str-replace

My question is if using array on str_replace is faster than doing it multiple times. My question goes for only two replaces.

With array

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

each search word once

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$newphrase = str_replace("fruits", "pizza", $phrase);

$newphrase = str_replace("vegetables", "beer", $phrase);
```

Comment: Probably. But the difference is probably immeasurably small. (Measure on your platform for a specific answer)

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: The fastest solution is to simply start with the code: `$phrase  = "You should eat pizza, beer, and fiber every day.";`

Comment: @PeterAjtai Hm.. true, why I didn't think of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/) on [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) :

```
// Outputs F because A is replaced with B, then B is replaced with C, and so on...
// Finally E is replaced with F, because of left to right replacements.
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);

// Outputs: apearpearle pear
// For the same reason mentioned above
$letters = array('a', 'p');
$fruit   = array('apple', 'pear');
$text    = 'a p';
$output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, $text);
echo $output;
```

Looking at those examples, PHP is applying the `str_replace` for each `$search` array node so both of your examples are the same in terms of performance however sure using an array for search and replace is more readable and future-prof as you can easily alter the array in future.

Comment: Yes, if your array was going to be bad you can give it a little slap on the index and make it a good little boy... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's faster but I tend do go with the array route because it's more maintainable and readable to me...

```
$replace = array();
$replace['fruits']     = 'pizza';
$replace['vegetables'] = 'beer';

$new_str = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $old_str);
```

If I had to guess I would say making multiple calls to str_replace would be slower but I'm not sure of the internals of str_replace. With stuff like this I've tended to go with readability/maintainability as the benefit to optimization is just not there as you might only get around 0.0005 seconds of difference depending on # of replacements.

If you really want to find out the time difference it's going to be close to impossible without building up a hugh dataset in order to get to the point where you can see an actual time difference vs anomalies from test confounds.

Using something like this ...

```
$start = microtime(true);
// Your Code To Benchmark
echo (microtime(true) - $start) . "Seconds"
```

... will allow you to time a request.

Comment: Secret tip: `strtr($old_str, $replace)` :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using this before and after each different method and you will soon see if there is a speed difference:

```
echo microtime()
```